# How to shift the background of multiple div boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

There seems to be an issue in my script and I can't figure out what it could be...

Here's the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XREw/)

I'm trying to shift the background of multiple div boxes. Evey second a random number is generated, if the correct one pops up, one of the divs is randomly selected and it's background shifted by `100px`. If the background on that div has already been shifted it'll get reverted to its original state.

## ***JavaScript***

---

```
div = document.getElementById('time');
write = document.getElementsByClassName('write');
data = [0, 0, 0, 0];
setInterval(function () {
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
div.innerHTML = num;
if (num == 1) {
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if (data[n] = 0) {
        write[n].style.backgroundPosition = '0px 100px';
        data[n] = 1;
    } else {
        write[n].style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
        data[n] = 0;
    }
}
}, 1000);
```

## ***CSS***

---

```
.write {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('http://daokun.webs.com/back.png');
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s cubic-bezier(.08, 1, .08, 1);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

## ***HTML***

---

```
<div id="time"></div>
<div class="write"></div>
<div class="write"></div>
<div class="write"></div>
<div class="write"></div>
<script src="Construct.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might want to choose a better title, if everything was titled javascript problem in here we'd have a serious problem all in all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple mistake

```
if (data[n] = 0) { // here you are always assigning the value 0 to data[n]
```

should be

```
if (data[n] === 0) { // here you are actually comparing data[n] with the value 0
```

Comment: Of course... How did I not notice that... I appologise for my stupid derp. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the jsfiddle still doesn't work. I took the liberty to rewrite and [**fork**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPQ9J/)  it:

```
div = document.querySelector('#time');
write = document.querySelectorAll('.write');
data = [0, 0, 0, 0];
setTimeout( slideBG, 1000 );

function slideBG(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    write[n].style['background-position'] = data[n] === 0 ? '0 100px' : '0 0';
    data[n] = Math.abs(data[n]-1);
    setTimeout(slideBG, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks alot simpler. I realy like the idea of the inline if statement.